# what is the output of this code?

Tags: sql, database

I have wriiten a part of code for you and I want to know the output ,I need your help because there is not any body for helping me also I think that the out put is A ,is this correct? thanks.

```
declare @v1 varchar(20),@v2 varchar(20)
select @v1 = 'NULL'
if @v1 is null and @v2 is null
select 'A'
else
select 'B'
```

EDITED: also what is the value of @ v2 ? thanks

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but it might help to specify what kind of database - Oracle, SQL Server, etc.

Comment: Why don't you run it and see?  Is this homework?

Comment: That must be homework...

Comment: i want to solve it with out running it with sql because in my midterm exam ther is no DBMS for solving my questions.

Comment: And having someone tell you the output of a very simple sql query is going to help you learn sql how, exactly? Sorry - you reasoning is unsound. You should at least execute it and then come here with a question about what you found.

Comment: you should *use* SQL to learn it

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you try it yourself?

The output will be `B` because `@v1` is assigned a string 'NULL' which is not the same as the special NULL meaning "no value"

Answer (score 1):

In MSSQL 2008 it returns B.  That is because @v1 is the string 'NULL', and not actually null.  If you change it to

```
select @v1 = null
```

Then it will return A

Comment: Since no value has been assigned to it (it was only declared), the value of @v2 is null.  So come to think of it, the "select @v1 = null" is really redundant, since it's already null to start with.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it's B because `= NULL` and `= 'NULL'` are two different things.

Answer (score 0):

@v2 is null, since you do not assing any value to it.
The output is B ´cause NULL is not the same as the string 'NULL'